# restapi lookup column sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to fetch an additional lookup column. From List A I have a field which is looked up in list B, and I have added an additional column from list A.  How to fetch from the additional column using the REST API?

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListB')/items?$select=Title,ListA/ProjectName,ListA/OM&$expand=ListA
```

I am getting "invialid column OM".

Comment: Write a separate request for ListA /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListA')/items?$select=Title and ListB ListA /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListB')/items?$select=Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest api $expand support below lookup additional fields only.

- Single line of text
- Date and Time
- Number

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the OM referenced from lista field type? belongs to above 3 field type?

Comment: also how to refer this lookup columns. I amm trying to display it in datatable tableContent += '<td>' + objArray[i].DM_x002f_TL + '</td>'; but it is returning undefined.